# Android onDraw get called again and again

Tags: android, ondraw

The code is simple :

```
public class myEditText extends EditText{
    ....

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        System.out.println("onDraw called.");
    }
    .....
}
```

I removed all other codes that may cause this view to be redrawn, but, it still get called again and again.

Any solution ? Thanks .

Comment: if you dont want your view to get drawn just call `setWillNotDraw(true);` in your initialization of your `myView`

Comment: I found the problem, myView is actually extended from EditText, if I change EditText to TextView, then onDraw will be called only once. So, the onDraw in EditText will be called constantly. But, why is it getting called when I did nothing? There's just one View(myView) in my activity, and it even has no focus ! BTW, setWillNotDraw(true) seems doesn't work with EditText.

Comment: It's probably just refreshing to draw the blinking text cursor.